# How to make a matrix multiplication in a task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am unable unable to get the product of matrices in a task in order to run it 
in several instances. I think the task is not properly doing the multiplication and calling several 0's.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _010029428_Multiplicacion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        int i, j, m, n;
        Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x000fff);
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de renglones y columnas: ");
        m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[,] a = new int[m, n];
        Console.WriteLine("first Matrix");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                a[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 4);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("First matrix is: ");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(a[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        int[,] b = new int[m, n];
        Console.WriteLine("Second Matrix: ");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                b[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 4);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The second matrix is:");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(b[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The result is :");
        int[,] c = new int[m, n];
        var multiplicacion = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                c[i, j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    c[i, j] += a[i, k] * b[k, j];
                }
            }
        });

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {

            multiplicacion.Start();

        }
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(c[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
}
}
```

The code is using multiplicacion.start() to run it asynchronously 
Not sure what the problem may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems.

**First**: You cannot create just one task and run it multiple times at once. New Task() must be created for each value of "i".

**Second**: You cannot use global variable ("j") and mutate it in a task that runs asynchronously, without proper synchronization. This would result in program crash or wrong result. Each task must have it's own (local) variable ("jj") if it needs to change it. Read-only variables (i, a, b, c, m, n) are usually safe to use, but it is better to pass them as arguments.

**Third**: You must wait for all tasks to finish before you write result to screen.

**Four**: Running task asynchronously has significant performance overhead. So unless you matrices are really huge (probably at least hundreads of rows and columns), calculating result in several asynchronous tasks is probably much slower than simple synchronous calculation on main thread.

Example of how to make it work follows. Code is still ugly and not wery good, but should work and give you some starting point for further improvements.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _010029428_Multiplicacion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int i, j, m, n;
            Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x000fff);
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de renglones y columnas: ");
            m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] a = new int[m, n];
            Console.WriteLine("first Matrix");
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    a[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 4);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("First matrix is: ");
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(a[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            int[,] b = new int[m, n];
            Console.WriteLine("Second Matrix: ");
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    b[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 4);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The second matrix is:");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(b[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The result is :");
            int[,] c = new int[m, n];

            Task[] tasks = new Task[m];
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                var multiplicacion = new Task((parameter) =>
                {
                    int ii = (int)parameter;

                    for (int jj = 0; jj < n; jj++)
                    {
                        c[ii, jj] = 0;
                        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                        {
                            c[ii, jj] += a[ii, k] * b[k, jj];
                        }
                    }
                },
                i);
                tasks[i] = multiplicacion;
                multiplicacion.Start();
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(c[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't understand the main issue of several tasks.